# Dell Inspiron N5110 Battery lasts only for 1.5 hours as opposed to 4 hours on Windows 7

Tags: dell, battery, overheating, inspiron

I've a Dell Inspiron N5110 laptop with the following specs:

- i5 processor
- 4 GB RAM
- NVIDIA GeForce GT540M
- Ubuntu 12.04LTS

My laptop is overheating and the battery is lasting for only about 1.5 hours. I had checked if the battery indicator was problematic but it turned out it wasn't. I drained the battery to it's least possible value and that came to around 1 hr 40 minutes. In fact, I've the same problem with Debian and Xubuntu as well. I would like to get some proper solution for this.

FYI: I've been having this problem since Ubuntu 11.04 but I'm not able to solve this in spite of trying various fixes like reducing brightness, Removing startup apps, Updating kernel and what not?. I'm a big fan of Ubuntu but this problem is stopping me from using Ubuntu and I'm using Win7 for 90% of the time.

Answer (score 1):

I think battery management on Ubuntu is just fine. To improve it, however, you can install Jupiter. According to WebUpd8.Org,

> Jupiter is an appindicator (it now uses Python instead of Mono) designed to improve laptops / netbooks battery life. It can be used to switch between maximum, high performance and power saving modes, change the screen resolution and orientation, enable or disable bluetooth, touchpad, WiFi (if available) and so on. If you own an Asus EeePC netbook, there's also a separate package that adds support for Asus Super Hybrid Engine (SHE) as well as some other EeePC tweaks.

To install Jupiter, enter the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/jupiter
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jupiter
```

[Source](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/04/things-to-tweak-after-installing-ubuntu.html)

[Is Ubuntu Battery Management Better Than Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137659/is-ubuntu-battery-management-better-than-windows)

I got same model but i7 ...this is awsome tool ..solved the problem

Comment: I have a Dell N4110, Core i5, after Jupiter my battery lasts 3 to 4 hours now.

Answer (score 0):

I found this very helpful and my problem is solved (for Dell Inspiron N511o):

- http://itbeginner.hubpages.com/hub/recovering-laptop-battery-home-solution

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

This happens mainly because of the NVIDIA GPU. Since NVIDIA optimus is not supported in Linux, the GPU is working all the time consuming a lot of battery power & generating heat. You can fix this by installing Bumblebee. It is an effort to bring the optimus support for linux.

You can find the instructions in the following link

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee#Installation